# Encrypting in PHP and decrypting in VBA

Tags: php, vba, encryption, xor

I encrypt sensitive data in PHP and process the data in Excel.

Here is the PHP code on the server to encrypt in hexadecimal:

```
function xor_string($string, $key) {
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) 
        $string[$i] = dechex(ord(($string[$i] ^ $key[$i % strlen($key)])));
    return $string;
}
```

The following code is used to decrypt the string in VBA:

```
Public Function XORDecryption(CodeKey As String, DataIn As String) As String
     Dim arkdata1 As Long
     Dim strDataOut As String
     Dim intXOrValue1 As Integer
     Dim intXOrValue2 As Integer
     
      For arkdata1 = 1 To (Len(DataIn) / 2)
          'The first value to be XOr-ed comes from the data to be encrypted
           intXOrValue1 = Val("&H" & (Mid$(DataIn, (2 * arkdata1) - 1, 2)))
          'The second value comes from the code key
           intXOrValue2 = Asc(Mid$(CodeKey, ((arkdata1 Mod Len(CodeKey)) + 1), 1))
           strDataOut = strDataOut + Chr(intXOrValue1 Xor intXOrValue2)
      Next arkdata1

      XORDecryption = strDataOut

 End Function
```

The encryption process:
With the string "123456897" and the key "2405" the PHP function return "011151314f0"

The decryption process:
With the string "011151314f0" and the key "2405" the VBA function return "5!d{0"

I can't find the reason why the VBA function does not return "123456897" :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah uhhh, even if you got this working it is pretty much as weak as crypto can possibly get and not likely to hold up to any level of analysis or attack. You should absolutely be using a proper crypto lib like OpenSSL in PHP and whatever the VBA equivalent is.

Comment: How sensitive is this data exactly? Because this "encryption" is really primitive, as the previous commenter mentioned. You should use an industry-standard encryption algorithm if you're serious about protecting this data.

Comment: The sensitiity of the data is limited. It's a code used to reconcile data from online survey with users data on my secured network. To do something with with the data, the hacker should hack my MySQL and have access to the excel file that is secured on my local network.